# What is the benefit of pyramid_celery if I am using a standard celeryconfig?

Tags: solr, rabbitmq, celery, pyramid

So I have a pyramid app which stores data in zodb (Substanced) and also creates a solr index for a speedy search of that data. Some of the solr indexing takes a while so I am wanting to make the solr indexing asynchronous. I am going to use rabbitmq and celery.

Do I benefit from using pyramid_celery? I don't want to use the ini file to store the celery config and there are no scheduled tasks so no celery beats. This is small scale and all of the processes/tasks will run on one machine.

Thanks

Comment: This is not exactly pyramid_celery, but Pyramid integration greatly inspired by pyramid_celery and warehouse. it lists some benefits of not pushing new tasks Celery directly, but using `Trassaction.afterCommitHook()` instead https://websauna.org/docs/narrative/misc/task.html

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I am answering my own question. I asked this on the pylons google group and the response from the author of pyramid_celery was

Absolutely nothing.  pyramid_celery is specifically for sharing your ini configuration / app configuration with your celery workers.  If you don't have a need to share those things you have no need for pyramid_celery :)

I will also look at Mikko's option.